# Reorder option is disabled in my account

Tags: magento-1.9

Some order display Recorder only. Check attachment.[image]

Comment: reorder link will be shown only if product is salable

Comment: Accept the answer If you find it helpful @Pratik

Comment: @KeyurShah I understand, But in my site there this mechanism is not working. I will explain you soon.

Answer (score 0):

Reorder link will display if your order status is not on `Hold` or `Payment review` and if product is `in-stock`. You can check `canReorder` function for more reference. In this place Magento perform the actual validation of `Reorder`. This function is written in `Mage_Sales_Model_Order`

```
protected function _canReorder($ignoreSalable = false)
    {
        if ($this->canUnhold() || $this->isPaymentReview() || !$this->getCustomerId()) {
            return false;
        }
        $products = array();
        foreach ($this->getItemsCollection() as $item) {
            $products[] = $item->getProductId();
        }
        if (!empty($products)) {
            /*
             * @TODO ACPAOC: Use product collection here, but ensure that product
             * is loaded with order store id, otherwise there'll be problems with isSalable()
             * for configurables, bundles and other composites
             *
             */
            /*
            $productsCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
                ->setStoreId($this->getStoreId())
                ->addIdFilter($products)
                ->addAttributeToSelect('status')
                ->load();
            foreach ($productsCollection as $product) {
                if (!$product->isSalable()) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            */
            foreach ($products as $productId) {
                $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                    ->setStoreId($this->getStoreId())
                    ->load($productId);
                if (!$product->getId() || (!$ignoreSalable && !$product->isSalable())) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        if ($this->getActionFlag(self::ACTION_FLAG_REORDER) === false) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```